# Getting more details about "applying selective sync" in Dropbox

Tags: windows-7, dropbox

When I change the selective sync parameters in Dropbox, it sometimes takes a while to apply the settings:

[image]

Is there any way to get more details on the current action (e.g. which file is being processed, how many files remains, etc.)? I am especially interested to assess how much remaining time the selective sync needs.

Answer (score 0):

The current feature of Dropbox does not provide that level of verbose detail on selective sync progression.

Process Monitor (procmon) from Sysinternals.

You can filter by:

- Process Name is Dropbox.exe
- Path contains the folder you want to include or exclude
- Operation is CreateFile

When you exclude (uncheck), Dropbox will recurse sequentially through the folder structure. You can guesstimate how far along you are based on the folder Dropbox is processing and the name of the file within that folder.